# Issue in setrepeating() in android alarmmanger?

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-service, alarmmanager

I have tried alarmanager in order to get daily notification in android.... The alarm do start at specified time but gets repeated every minute after that...I have specified INTERVAL_DAY in setrepeating() function of Mainactivity but it does not seems to work. It contains three parts Mainactivity, MyReceiver & AlarmService. Can anyone seems to fix this ??

**Mainactivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

// we can set time by open date and time picker dialo

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Log.e("Tag","calling here");
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),864000, pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

**MyReceiver**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    int MID=0;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle("Alaram Fired")
                .setContentText("Events To be PErformed").setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        notificationManager.notify(MID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
        MID++;

    }

}
```

**MyAlarmService**

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service
{
    private NotificationManager mManager;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        Log.e("Tag1","alarmservice here");
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
       //notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "Daily Notification Demo", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);
        mManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: You are facing this issue on specific android version or all android os versions.??? @user5158017

Comment: use AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY instead of 86400L, check both the values. and use setInexactRepeating

Comment: I am facing this issue on all android versions...... i have tried with Alarmmanger.INTERVAL_DAY & setInexactRepeating but the same problem persist !

Answer (score 0):

**AlarmManager.setRepeating** doesn't work properly on different android versions.

Try **setExact**. It won't repeat but you can achieve repeating functionality as mentioned below:

**Update MyReceiver**

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (864000 + System.currentTimeMillis()),pendingIntent);
```

Here we schedule alarm again by calculating nextAlarmTime using 864000 + System.currentTimeMillis();